# How to add a new column with some constant value while appending two datasets using Groovy?

Tags: groovy, dataset, analytics

I have multiple monthly datasets with 50 variables each. I need to append these datasets to create one single dataset. However, I also want to add the month's name to the corresponding records while appending such that I can see a new column in the final dataset which can be used to identify records belonging to a month.

Example:

Data 1: Monthly_file_201807

```
ID   |   customerCategory    |    Amount   |
1    |    home               |    654.00   |
2    |    corporate          |    9684.65  |
```

Data 2: Monthly_file_201808

```
ID   |   customerCategory    |    Amount   |
84   |    SME                |    985.29   |
25   |    Govt               |    844.88   |
```

On Appending, I want something like this:

```
ID   |   customerCategory    |    Amount   |   Month  |
1    |    home               |    654.00   |   201807 |
2    |    corporate          |    9684.65  |   201807 |
84   |    SME                |    985.29   |   201808 |
25   |    Govt               |    844.88   |   201808 |
```

currently, I'm appending using following code:

```
List dsList = [

Data1Path,
Data2Path
].collect() {app.data.open(source:it)}

//concatenate all records into a single larger dataset
Dataset ds=app.data.create()

dsList.each(){
ds.prepareToAdd(it) 
ds.addAll(it)
}
ds.save()

app.data.copy(in: ds, out: FinalAppendedDataPath)
```

I have used the standard append code, but unable to add that additional column with a fixed value of month in there. I don't want to loop through the data to create an additional column of "month", as my data is very large and I have multiple files.

Comment: what is `Dataset`?

Comment: any file. It could be csv, txt or any other file format

Comment: I mean what library are you using?

Comment: it's a company IP, so can't disclose it. but it is similar to DataFrame in python obtained by reading a csv file

Comment: then I'm affraid nobody will be able to help you out here

Comment: If it helps, it accepts all the other libraries accessible through public Java platforms or Groovy platforms.

Comment: no it won't, as it has nothing to do with java or groovy. What we can help you with is `I don't want to loop through the data`

Comment: @injecteer if you can help me avoid the loop to create an static variable, that would also be very helpful

Comment: If I only knew what you meant...